# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined for my sortBy function in my React component and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a container component in my React project that houses two separate components. One component is a list of locations and the other is a filtering section for that list.

The filter section dispatches an action up to the container and the container re orders the list based on the criteria and passes a final "filtered" list back to the locations list component.

Right now the Sort By filter is a select dropdown with option values set to strings (as shown below), that are then passed up to the container.

```
<SelectDropdown value={sort} onChange={handleSortChange}>
  <option value={''}>Select</option>
  <option value={'alphaAsc'}>Alphabetical Asc</option>
  <option value={'alphaDesc'}>Alphabetical Desc</option>
</SelectDropdown>
```

Inside the container I have a simple alphabetical sortBy function to sort and render the list in ascending or descending order based on the address value, and that's where my app keeps crashing and throwing the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined` but I'm not entirely sure why.

My original function is below along with the line where I'm using it.

`Alphabetical Sort function`

```
export const alphabeticalSort = property => {
  let sortOrder = 1;

  if (property[0] === '-') {
    sortOrder = -1;
    property = property.substr(1);
  }

  return function(a, b) {
    if (sortOrder === -1) {
      return b[property].localeCompare(a[property]);
    } else {
      return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);
    }
  };
};
```

`How I'm calling it`

```
if (sort === 'alphaAsc') {
 filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort(alphabeticalSort(l => l.address.addressLine1)).slice();
}
```

`Filtered Locations`

```
const allLocations = store.get('locations');
let filteredLocations = allLocations.slice();
```

`Location Structure`

```
locations: [
    {
      name: 'Fictional Place',
      address: {
                addressLine1: '123 Imaginary Drive',
                line2: '',
                city: 'Philadelphia',
                state: 'PA'
                zip: '12345'
               }
              ...
    },
    {
      name: 'California Dreaming',
      address: {
                addressLine1: '456 Somewhere Blvd',
                line2: '',
                city: 'Sacramento',
                state: 'CA'
                zip: '67890'
               }
             ...
    },
    ....
```

Comment: Add `filteredLocations` to your question

Comment: Just added the filteredLocations and what the location structure looks like

Comment: Were you able to get help from the below answer?

Comment: Hey unfortunately not, It's throwing a new error now saying ```TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined```

Comment: How did you call the function, can you post that? What did you pass inside `alphabeticalSort`?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay! This is the function: ```export const ascendingSort = property => {
  let sortOrder = 1;
  let propArr;

  if (property[0] === '-') {
    sortOrder = -1;
    propArr = property.split('.');
  }

  return function(a, b) {
    if (sortOrder === -1) {
      return b[propArr[0]][propArr[1]].localeCompare(a[propArr[0]][propArr[1]]);
    } else {
      return a[propArr[0]][propArr[1]].localeCompare(b[propArr[0]][propArr[1]]);
    }
  };
};```

Comment: And here's how I'm calling it: ```if (sort === 'alphaAsc') {
      filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort(ascendingSort(l => l.address.addressLine1)).slice();
    }```

Comment: Please check in my answer how I am calling the function `alphabeticalSort`.. with what arguments

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like below, you enter the property as a string with `"."`

```js
let locations = [{
    name: 'Fictional Place',
    address: {
      addressLine1: '123 Imaginary Drive',
      line2: '',
      city: 'Philadelphia',
      state: 'PA',
      zip: '12345'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'California Dreaming',
    address: {
      addressLine1: '456 Somewhere Blvd',
      line2: '',
      city: 'Sacramento',
      state: 'CA',
      zip: '67890'
    }
  }
]

const alphabeticalSort = property => {    
  let sortOrder = 1 // Add your logic for asc/desc here
  , propArr = property.split(".")
  
  return function(a, b) {    
    if (sortOrder === -1) {
      return b[propArr[0]][propArr[1]].localeCompare(a[propArr[0]][propArr[1]]);
    } else {
      return a[propArr[0]][propArr[1]].localeCompare(b[propArr[0]][propArr[1]]);
    }
  };
};

console.log(locations.sort(alphabeticalSort("address.addressLine1")))
console.log(locations.sort(alphabeticalSort("address.state")))
```